# Loading larger than memory PQ/Arrow file using Polars in python

Tags: python, large-data, python-polars

I have a 50GB large Arrow file. I am trying to read it with 12GB RAM (what is avlbl on google colab). However, the session crashes after it runs out of memory.

Ops done:

1. load the PQ/Arrow file
2. group by last 6cols
3. find some basic stats as shown in code
4. don't run out of mem

Code:

```
import polars as pl

def prepare_summary_report_polars(parquet_path):
    # Lazily read the Parquet file
    lazy_df = pl.scan_parquet(parquet_path)

    # Use the last 6 columns for group-by operations
    last_6_cols = lazy_df.columns[-6:]

    # Create new columns for positive and negative/zero 'PnL'
    lazy_df = lazy_df.with_columns([
        (pl.col("PnL") * (pl.col("PnL") > 0)).alias("positive_PnL"),
        (pl.col("PnL") * (pl.col("PnL") <= 0)).alias("negative_or_zero_PnL")
    ])

    # Perform a single group-by operation with all required calculations
    summary_df_lazy = (lazy_df
                        .groupby(last_6_cols)
                        .agg([
                            pl.sum("positive_PnL").alias("abs_profit"),
                            pl.sum("positive_PnL").is_not_null().sum().alias("abs_profit_cnt"),
                            pl.sum("negative_or_zero_PnL").alias("abs_loss"),
                            pl.sum("negative_or_zero_PnL").is_not_null().sum().alias("abs_loss_cnt"),
                            pl.sum("PnL").alias("net_pnl"),
                            pl.col("PnL").count().alias("trade_cnt")
                        ]))

    # Collect the summary data, thereby evaluating the lazy DataFrame
    summary_df = summary_df_lazy.collect(streaming=True)

    return summary_df


#running on colab
LARGE_PQ_TEST = '/content/large_test.parquet'
summary_df = prepare_summary_report_polars(LARGE_PQ_TEST)
summary_df
```

Can someone tell me what needs to change to make it work ?
I also made another failed attempt using:

```
#Runs out of mem
df = pl.read_ipc('/content/large_test.arrow', use_pyarrow=False, memory_map=True,)
```

Comment: Do `.explain(streaming=True)` and look for stuff outside the PIPELINE